# 500 Internal Server Error in PHP files

Tags: php, apache, error-handling

I have a problem. I installed CentOS Web Panel and varnish cache on my VPS server. I have two domains, two hosts on a VPS. One website is using WordPress other is not. Now everything on non-wordpress site is working (html,js,css,picture files...) fine except that PHP files are not working now(Same on WordPress). Just one file is working named `testmail.php`, which contains: `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`
Here is apache error log:

```
[Sat Jul 04 16:29:29 2015] [error] [client 172.***.***.***] Premature end of script headers: testip.php
[Sat Jul 04 16:29:37 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Jul 04 16:29:39 2015] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sat Jul 04 16:29:39 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
[Sat Jul 04 16:29:40 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 04 16:42:07 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Jul 04 16:42:21 2015] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sat Jul 04 16:42:21 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
[Sat Jul 04 16:42:22 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I've noticed that i have two `php.ini` files one is at `/etc/php.ini` other is at `/usr/local/php/php.ini` (used by server) and I also have two `httpd.conf` files one is at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` other is at `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf` (used by server). I've also noticed that there are no modules(`mod_rewrite.so`.. or any other) in second apache config file(used by server).

I tried to change ownership (chown) and tried to change file permissions (chmod) but nothing works. Can you help please?

Comment: This looks like a system where _two_ separate installation attempts were made: one using the package management and once "wild" bypassing the package management. You should clean that up, since you should know the base you are working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 Internal Server Error occurs from following reason. you can solve by followng:-
1.If you have not given file permsission you can get this error. Please give file permission.

2. Or Open Apache’s httpd.conf file 
   you have to find following lines, and remove #

   ## LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

## LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

3. you can also check your htaccess is file or folder is allowed or not.